# Can you use #Temp table in dynamic SQL when in OPENROWSET?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to use #Temp tables in my dynamic SQL in Microsoft SQL Server 2014, and it works fine locally, but if I put it inside an OPENROWSET so I can gather data from another server, it gets error:

> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "(null)" returned
>   message "Deferred prepare could not be completed.". Msg 8180, Level
>   16, State 1, Line 9 Statement(s) could not be prepared. Msg 208, Level
>   16, State 1, Line 9 Invalid object name '#RefmdCodeList'

Is that just not allowed? Or is there some different way I need to do it?

To simplify the issue, here are two examples.  
**THIS WORKS:**

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) 
set @sql =  N' select * from #RefmdCodeList'
exec(@sql)
```

**THIS DOES NOT WORK:**

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) 
set @sql = N'   SELECT * FROM
                    OPENROWSET(''SQLNCLI'', 
                    ''Server=' + @PAFServer + ';Database=' +@PAFDatabase +';UID=p2kservices;PWD=P0werP@th!'',
                      N'' SELECT * from #RefmdCodeList'')'
exec(@sql)
```

For people who might ask, below is what I'm really trying to do. If I remove the #Temp tables, my code as written below runs fine. With the #Temp tables included, I get error message above.

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) 
set @sql = N'   SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(''SQLNCLI'', ''Server=' + @PAFServer + ';Database=' +@PAFDatabase +';UID=p2kservices;PWD=P0werP@th!'',
N'' ;WITH spec_data (entity, accession_no, acc_id, spec_id, spec_description, spec_label, spec_sc_code) AS
(SELECT ''''PAMF'''' AS entity, a.accession_no, a.id, asp.id, asp.description, asp.specimen_label, substring(''''88''''+spec_sc.code, 1,5)
FROM accession_2 a (NOLOCK)
JOIN acc_specimen asp (nolock) ON asp.acc_id = a.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN acc_charges spec_ac (NOLOCK) on spec_ac.acc_id = asp.acc_id 
        AND spec_ac.rec_id = asp.id AND spec_ac.rec_type = ''''S''''
LEFT OUTER JOIN service_code spec_sc (NOLOCK) on spec_sc.id = spec_ac.service_code_id
JOIN acc_refmd aref (NOLOCK) ON aref.acc_id = a.id
WHERE recv_date >= ''''+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@SDate, 101) +'''' and recv_date < ''''+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@EDate, 101)+''''
AND aref.refmd_id in (SELECT id from #RefmdCodeList)
) 
SELECT DISTINCT entity accession_no, asp.acc_id, spec_id, spec_description, spec_label, 
    spec_sc_code, substring(''''88''''+lab_sc.code, 1,5)
FROM spec_data asp
LEFT OUTER JOIN acc_charges lab_ac (NOLOCK) on lab_ac.acc_id = asp.acc_id and rec_type = ''''L''''
JOIN service_code lab_sc (NOLOCK) on lab_sc.id = lab_ac.service_code_id
JOIN acc_order ord (NOLOCK) on ord.id = lab_ac.rec_id 
        AND ord.acc_specimen_id = asp.spec_id
WHERE substring(''''88''''+spec_sc.code, 1,5) in (SELECT service_code from #ServiceCodeList) 
OR substring(''''88''''+lab_sc.code, 1,5) in (SELECT service_code from #ServiceCodeList)
'') '
```

Comment: A temp table is only visible from your local session.  It's not available in a linked server query.

Answer (score 0):

> Is that just not allowed?

A #temp table is visible only to the current running session. Even openrowset() to the local server will not see the #temp table because openrowset executes on a different connection(& another session).

> Or is there some different way I need to do it?

You could populate a staging table on the remote server and use that staging table pretending/as if it was a #table. Generic staging tables (with an int column and a varchar column) for passing through values work pretty well. In order to differentiate between parallel processes the staging table could have a sessionid column (which holds the @@spid on the local side).

For inspiration....

```
--local temp table
create table #localtemp
(
    srvcode varchar(100)
);
insert into #localtemp(srvcode)
select @@servername + '-' + name
from sys.objects;

--populate a proxy table on the remote server
declare @foo int;
select @foo = objectid
from openrowset('SQLNCLI', 'Server=Universe;Trusted_Connection=yes', 
'set fmtonly off;

if object_id(''tempdb.dbo.proxyservicetable'') is null
begin
    create table tempdb.dbo.proxyservicetable
    (
        sessionid smallint,
        servicecode varchar(100)
    );

    create clustered index uclxproxyservicetable on tempdb.dbo.proxyservicetable(sessionid);
end

select object_id(''tempdb.dbo.proxyservicetable'') as objectid;
');

select @foo as stagingtableobjectid --on the remoteservers

--cleanup any staging leftovers from previous executions
delete from
openrowset('SQLNCLI', 'Server=Universe;Trusted_Connection=yes', 
'
select *
from tempdb.dbo.proxyservicetable;
')
where sessionid = @@spid;

--populate staging with values from the current execution (#localtemp as source)
insert into
openrowset('SQLNCLI', 'Server=Universe;Trusted_Connection=yes', 
'
select *
from tempdb.dbo.proxyservicetable;
')
select @@spid, srvcode
from #localtemp;

--passthrough query, at the remote server
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
select @sql = 'select *
from openrowset(''SQLNCLI'', ''Server=Universe;Trusted_Connection=yes'', 
'' select @@servername,* from tempdb.dbo.proxyservicetable where sessionid =' + cast(@@spid as varchar(10)) + '''
)';
exec(@sql);
go

drop table #localtemp
go
```